# How to return a multi valued field from SOLR

Tags: solr

Just wanted to know if there is a way to return a multi valued from Solr suggester?

For eg. I have an address with the following fields:

```
number_first
street_name
locality_name
state
postcode
```

Sample address:

```
number_first     7
street_name      Mitchell
locality_name    Hunter
state            ISB
postcode         2901
```

and I create a field:

```
<field name="address" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

  <copyField source="number_first" dest="address"/>
  <copyField source="street_name" dest="address"/>
  <copyField source="locality_name" dest="address"/>
  <copyField source="state" dest="address"/>
  <copyField source="postcode" dest="address"/>
```

With the suggester:

```
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">address</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
<str name="maxEdits">1</str>
<str name="storeDir">fuzzy_suggestions</str>
```

Is it possible to return all the values in the address field while doing suggester search? Currently, if I search for a street_name and if it is matched, only the street_name is returned back.

```
term    "Mitchell"
weight  0
payload ""
```